# Enable visibility of label when a certain selected value is selected in a drop down list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to make it so when the user selects a certain item it gives the user some information by setting the visible property of a label to "true", it should be relatively simple but i can't seem to make it work. I'm using Web Forms.

Aspx code:

```
<label for="footerPlaceHolder_twoFactorAuthentication" class="sr-only"><asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, SelectTwoFactor %>"></asp:Localize></label>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList"  OnSelectedIndexChange="twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList_SelectedIndex" CssClass="selectpicker">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, SelectTwoFactor %>"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, RequireTwoFactor %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, RecommendTwoFactor %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorNotRequired %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                    <p><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="paymentDay" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, ValidationPaymentDayRequired %>" InitialValue="0" EnableClientScript="true" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></p>

<h3><asp:Localize runat="server" ID="noticeLabel" Visible="false" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, Notice %>"></asp:Localize></h3>
                    <h5 class="leftspace"><asp:Localize runat="server" ID="noticeText" Visible="false" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, NoticeInfo %>"></asp:Localize></h5>
```

What I've tried:

```
$(function(){
    if($("#twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList").val() == 3)
        $("#noticeText").visible("true");
    });
```

Comment: What is #noticeinfo? I cannot see any element with that ID.

Comment: If you made a server control (i.e. runat="server") invisible, it is not rendered to the HTML. So, javascript show/hide will not work at all. The JS simply does not know about it's existence.

Comment: The correct syntax for showing an element in JQuery is: $('#someId').show();

Comment: Don't forget to add a change event handler to the dropdown.

Comment: @Rocker1985 the ID was suppose to be "noticeText", I've made the changes but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspx code:

```
<label for="footerPlaceHolder_twoFactorAuthentication" class="sr-only"><asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorSelect %>"></asp:Localize></label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList" CssClass="selectpicker" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorSelect %>"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorRequire %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorRecommend %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorNotRequired %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                <p><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList" CssClass="field-validation-error"  InitialValue="3" EnableClientScript="true" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></p>

                <span ID="noticeinfo" class="leftspace"><asp:Localize runat="server"  ID="noticeText" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, NoticeInfo %>"></asp:Localize></span>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, twofactorMessage0 %>" ID="twofactorMessage0" />
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, twofactorMessage1 %>" ID="twofactorMessage1" />
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, twofactorMessage2 %>" ID="twofactorMessage2" />
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, twofactorMessage3 %>" ID="twofactorMessage3" />
```

working js. code:

```
$('#footerPlaceHolder_twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList').on('change', function (e) {
        var selectedValue = $('#footerPlaceHolder_twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList').val();
        console.log("Value of dropdown is: " + selectedValue);

    $('#noticeinfo').text($('#footerPlaceHolder_twofactorMessage' + selectedValue).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    if($("#twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList :selected").val() === '3') {
        $("#noticeinfo").visible("true");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the final DOM rendered on the page.